# what is the correct way to implement select() + threadpool?

Tags: c, select

```
Server:

socket()
bind()
listen()
for(;;) {
    select()
    if it is listenfd {
        accept()
        add to fd_set
    } else {
        add task to thread_pool work queue
        threadpool_add(thread_routine)
    }
}

thread_routine() {
    get connection fd
    read()
    write()
    close(connection fd)
}
```

This design has a problem, while `select` waits for data from `socket_fd`, another thread may `close(socket_fd)`, this will cause `select` return and `read(socket_fd)` return `EBADF`. What is the right design?

Comment: this is not C code ... and to partly answer your question : use [mutexes](http://www.skrenta.com/rt/man/pthread_mutex_init.3.html) and check if the socket still is open before you use it

Comment: @specializt I think it is no need to paste the code, I write like this just aim to make it simple and easy to understand. I have thought about using mutexes, but it will slow down the server.

Comment: why would you think that using mutexes will "slow down a server"? That doesnt make much sense ...

Comment: @specializt Cause I think there is no need to do synchronizing.

Comment: un-hunh ...that doesnt answer my question - and your "thoughts" also make no sense ... without synchronization you will create racing conditions at some point, thats just how the technology works. This program will crash some time, this "need" actually is a technological requirement **unless** you implement your own atomicity ... which is pretty hard to do

Comment: @specializt I don't mean synchronization is bad, I mean sometimes there are better designs than synchronization.

Comment: synchronization is the only actual solution to concurrent field access - there is literally no "better design" in existence ... as long as you keep the algorithms on the same physical machine. You can decorate your field access nicely and you can pretend to avoid it - which actually puts the racing condition further into the future but .... it **will** happen, no matter how beautiful your code is, no matter how clever your design may be

Comment: @specializt Eg. I have a global variable maybe used by multi threads, if all the threads do the same thing, read and write the global variable. Then I can create this variable for each thread. Also, this doesn't answer your question. If there is really a situation which must use synchronization, then I agree with you.

Comment: .... what? Yes, you can *"create"* variables for *"each thread"* - since every thread uses its own version there will be no problem, of course ... but if each thread uses the **same** variable *(read : "global variable")* then you will have a problem. I think you may want to read an introduction about concurrency and multithreading ... its rather important knowledge, trust me; its also worthwile and can be fun. Also : there is nothing to be *"agreed"* upon, racing conditions are simple, empirical **facts** yet not many people know about them ... granted : its a bit advanced

Comment: @specializt Yep, I have already read Programming with Posix Threads

Comment: @specializt Could you suggest some classic books or articles about concurrency and multi-threading?

Comment: i, for one dont do books - too many assumptions, claims and weirdly convoluted, misguided statements. Im intrinsically autodidactic and thats **much** harder than just reading books - but it works. So i guess i cant help you there but most assuredly **some**one will and theres also google. But do yourself a major favor and dont just believe the very first author who answers your question - singular people have ... singular minds and once theirs has been branded with their own idea they start making stuff up ... always consider more than one explanation.

Comment: @specializt Good suggestion. Thanks. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically okay. The mistake is in having `thread_routine` call `close` on the socket. It is never okay to destroy a resource while another thread is, or might be, using it. If this is TCP, a better option would be to call `shutdown` on the socket.

Comment: Yes, `close` socket in another thread is not right. But `shutdown` will cause socket resources not released. Could you suggest a good design?

Comment: @CharlesLiuChina The thread that calls `shutdown` does that as the very last thing it ever does to the socket. When the thread that calls `select` notices that the socket has been shut down, it can call `close` on it since it now knows that no other thread could be using that socket. (You can also use a reference count. When you detect a fatal error on a socket, you decrement its reference count and close it if the count reaches zero.)

Comment: Help! How to know a socket is `shutdown()` by another thread and not cause blocking or race condition?

Comment: @CharlesLiuChina You have two choices. First, you could arrange things so that you don't have to know. If you detect a fatal error or normal shutdown in the `select` thread, and you know no other thread is doing anything with the socket, do you care why it failed? If there is some application-specific reason why you need to know this, then just track it somewhere, say in a shared state variable associated with the socket. Perhaps in the same thing that told the thread to call `select` on it and told the other thread(s) to exchange data on it.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for your detailed explanation. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would be a better way to design your application:

- One listen-thread accepts connections (i.e. only `select`s the listen fd)
- For each accepted connection, immediately create a new thread or hand the fd to an existing idle thread
- Select the client fds in their own threads for input (not in the listener thread)

This is a more intuitive design and should eliminate your problem. You might even be able use blocking IO (without select) in the client threads, depending on the protocol used.

Comment: which thread should I close the client fd from `accept` call?

Comment: in the client thread, when it is done with the connection. Since the listener thread selects only its listen-fd it will not be disturbed from this action

Comment: I rethink your design, but how to integrate threadpool to your design? I think it is a waste to create and destroy threads again and again.

Comment: As I said, you do not have to do that... You can pass the fds to idle worker threads after accepting them through a queue

Comment: I see. Thanks. ^_^